# Sharepoint development - very large pages

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

We have a need to create Sharepoint pages that will replace procedure files (so they can be view online without downloading) but will be extremely large (eg up to 100 page in the old pdfs).

I am new to Sharepoint development, and I am not sure if this is possible. Putting the entire content in a single page would be a severe problem for browsers and page loading speeds even in static HTML files.

One idea is to break the pages into sections, each one in its own page, and then have a central dashboard page which can load a selected selection one at a time (removing any previously loaded sections to reduce memory usage in the browser), based on user interaction, either using javascript (eg jquery.load()) or using web part code
SPHttpClient
SPHttpClientResponse

Is this at all possible eg using spfx?

ps. Even better, if the dashboard page could not only load the sections, but allow editing and posting back!

Or any alternative solutions would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

Here are my suggestions using SharePoint online out of the box features:

1. You must be having sections/topics in your PDF file. Create a site page for each topic in your PDF file.
2. Create a SharePoint site page where you will be adding links to all above site pages in "Table of contents" format.
3. You can use Text web part to create links to pages.

**Documentation**: [Add text, tables, and images to your page with the Text web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-text-tables-and-images-to-your-page-with-the-text-web-part-729c0aa1-bc0d-41e3-9cde-c60533f2c801)